# Проблема с ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Есть сайт (Razor), на странице cshtml:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#Search").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/GetNodes/",
                data: JSON.stringify("100"),
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function (request, status, err) {
                    alert(request + " " + status + " " + err);
                }
            });
        });
</script>

<input type="button" id="Search" title="Search" value="Search" />
```

Контроллер App_Code/HomeController.cs:

```
public class HomeController:Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetNodes(string key)
    {
        return Json(true);
    }

}
```

Global.asax:

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Mvc" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>
<script runat="server">
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RouteTable.Routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
    }
</script>
```

По нажатию на кнопку всегда срабатывает часть error для ajax запроса. Что необходимо добавить/исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй сделать так:`data:JSON.stringify({key:"100"})`